# Is there a way to wrap input types to a template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Long story short, I have written a piece of code like below. This snippet includes a two-type template class. And its name is Num.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename N, typename U>
class Num
{
public:
    Num(): num0(3), num1(4.56) 
    {
        cout << "This is number: " << num0 << endl;
        cout << "This is number: " << num1 << endl;
    }
private:
    N num0;
    U num1;
};

int main()
{

    Num<int, double> num();

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine but for some reason I need to wrap the types while passing to class instance. To be more clear, instead of having:

```
Num<int, double> num();
```

I need to have something like this:

```
Num<(int, double)> num();
```

I want this for testing a two-typed class in google typed-test when you enter your types to be tested as a TYPED_TEST_CASE macro.

Comment: Isn't `Num<(int, double)> num();` equivalent to `Num<double> num();` , which should give a compiler error for your class.

Comment: You could pass it as a function type, like `void (int, double)` and extract the parameter types from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need exactly this syntax

```
Num<(int, double)> num();
```

no, I don't think it's possible.

If you need to wrap a couple of types in only one, sure: you can use `std::tuple` with specialization

```
template <typename>
class Num;

template <typename N, typename U>
class Num<std::tuple<N, U>>
{
public:
    Num(): num0(3), num1(4.56) 
    {
        cout << "This is number: " << num0 << endl;
        cout << "This is number: " << num1 << endl;
    }
private:
    N num0;
    U num1;
};

// ...

Num<std::tuple<int, double>> num{};
```

or zillion of other similar ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what i was looking for and because my little experience I didn't knew it. Lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a function type, like `void (int, double)`, and extract the types from there:

```
// ...

template<typename T>
struct NumHelper;

template<typename N, typename U>
struct NumHelper<void (N, U)>
{ using type = Num<N, U>; };

template<typename T>
using NumHelperT = typename NumHelperT<T>::type;

// ...

int main()
{
    NumHelperT<void (int, double)> num{};
}
```

Note: don't use `Num<int, double> num()` as it is a function declaration.